# Android Volley Request

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I am trying to build an app that will get some information from a server, so that I can display it to the user.

I was told to check out Volley as a way to do this.

I am trying to do this in a fragment, and only have the one activity(Main_Activity), and just swap out fragments as needed.

In my login fragment I have this code:

```
public class loginFragment extends Fragment {

//Local Vars
private boolean loginCheck = false;

//required constructor
public loginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
}

//When login button is clicked, this method is called
private void login(View view) {
    String username;
    String password;

    username = getView().findViewById(R.id.enteredUsername).toString();
    password = getView().findViewById(R.id.enteredPassword).toString();





    final ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] unameSeparated = new String[username.length()];
    unameSeparated = username.split("(?!^)");

    String startUrl = "https://us.api.battle.net/d3/profile/";
    String uname = "";
    String APIKey = "/?(pretend this is my API key)";

    //Separating the username into the parts needed for sending request
    for (int i = 0; i < unameSeparated.length; i++) {
        if ((unameSeparated[i].equals("#"))) {
            //Replacing # with '%23'
            uname += "%23";
        } else {
            uname += unameSeparated[i];
        }
    }

    String url = startUrl + uname+ APIKey;

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    info.add(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loginCheck;
}



}
```

So when the user enters their username, and hits the login button it should send the request to the server, and get their data and put it into an arraylist(I'm going to change it to put it into a file later I think, or even just a variable)

The way that this is set up currently, when I run it, I get an error when I click the log in button, and it says:

```
04-28 18:55:40.358 6224-6224/com.hfad.diablo3assistant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.hfad.diablo3assistant, PID: 6224
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:441)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:432)
                                                                         at com.hfad.diablo3assistant.MainActivity.swapFragment(MainActivity.java:76)
                                                                         at com.hfad.diablo3assistant.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3450)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:368)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4042)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Code from main activity for getting menu options selected:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int item_id = item.getItemId();
    switch (item_id) {
        case R.id.accDetails:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.personalProfileLookup:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.favoriteCharacters:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.friendProfileLookup:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
        case R.id.tipsAndTricks:
            swapFragment(item_id);
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Code from main activity for swapping fragments:

```
private void swapFragment(int fragmentID){

    TextView tracker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentFragDisplay);

    Fragment fragment = null;
    if(fragmentID == R.id.personalProfileLookup) {
        tracker.setText("My Profile");
        fragment = new Personal_Profile_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.favoriteCharacters) {
        tracker.setText("Favorite Characters");
        fragment = new Favorite_Characters_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.friendProfileLookup) {
        tracker.setText("Friend Lookup");
        fragment = new Friend_Profile_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.tipsAndTricks) {
        tracker.setText("Tips and Tricks");
        fragment = new TipsandTricks_Fragment();
    } else if(fragmentID == R.id.accDetails) {
        tracker.setText("Log In");
        fragment = new loginFragment();
    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: Your posted stack trace includes `MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected` and `MainActivity.swapFragment`; these don't seem to have anything to do with the login button or the code you've posted.

Comment: Hmm, alright, I'll check out that code

Comment: I have edited the doc, where the error may come from then, but the fragments all swap out correctly I think. Which is why I don't understand why the error is there.

Comment: The error only occurs when I actually click the login button, but swapping fragments from the menu is fine. I don't understand what could be causing this with just the button...

Comment: There's still an unanswered question of why the stack trace you posted includes `MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected`. Are you clicking a button to perform the login? Or are you using an overflow menu? How is `login()` called?

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected is called when someone clicks on the action bar at the top, and clicks on a fragment to load from there. The login button shouldn't be calling this method, which is why im confused.

You click login to call the login method in the first section of code I posted, and it should stay in the fragment. Login should only send the request to the other server. It shouldn't leave the fragment.

onOptionsItemSelected is in the main activity, and the login function is in the fragment, not activity.

Login is a button in the fragment

Comment: If it helps any, in the loginFragment's XML I use this:

            android:onClick="login". I dont know if that tries to go to the main activity or not.